# I want to get users to choose a campus and return an error message if they enter an invalid option. My code only prints the error message

Tags: python, while-loop

```
def camp():
    final_campus = input("Enter campus are you enrolled to: Cape Town, Johannesburg, Durban, or Phokeng")
    while final_campus!="Johannesburg" or "Cape Town" or "Durban" or "Phokeng":
        print("Please enter a valid campus: either 'Johannesburg', 'Cape Town', 'Durban', or 'Phokeng'")
        break
    else:
        return final_campus
```

Comment: you should prefer using Enum and asking only number from user not typing full words

Comment: make a List with all name and use 
`if final_campus not in *list*: 
    --your code--      `


Also as @Drako said it would be best to do a dict for example with ids and name!
If you want to check the input you just use dict.values()

Comment: def camp():
    camps=("Johannesburg", "Cape Town", "Durban", "Phokeng")
    while True:
        final_campus = input("fc: ")
        if final_campus in camps:
            return final_campus